# what is the size or model of an add-a-tee(similar stuff) can convert a toilet water outlet working both for a toilet water tank and a washing machine

Tags: water

I bought a washing machine because I'm living in an apartment where no in-house washing machine for the pandemic period.

The toilet water supply outlet is 3/8``, it looks like the photo below:
[image]

Now I need to convert it into an extra outlet so it can works for both the toilet and my washing machine at the same time.

The washing machine hose is 3/4`` like the photo below:
[image]

So I guess the most convenient solution is to buy a 3-way Add-A-Tee 3/8`` inlet and 3/8`` outlet, 3/4`` outlet, it should look similar to this:

[image: Add-A-Tee]

Unfortunately, I have been looking online for hours, but I couldn't find the correct one, I'm not sure if I didn't type the correct keywords or such size doesn't exist.

If someone is more familiar with this area, could you help me to find it out, it can be on Amazon, eBay, or any e-commerce(I'm living in Canada, but as long as I know this the model, I should be able to find a vendor deliverable to my home).

If this Add-A-Tee or adaptor doesn't exist, can someone know how to deal with such a problem?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Where will it drain and where will you plug it in?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a rental, I do **not** recommend this at all. If anything goes wrong, and things can go **very** wrong, you will have a flood on your hands and your landlord will not be happy.

If you own this apartment, I do **not** recommend this at all. The chances of things going wrong are relatively big, and even if everything works correctly, the flow rate will be very low because this connection is designed for a toilet and won't simply "scale up" to fill a washing machine.

Think about all the pieces needed, normally, for a washing machine:

- Cold water in
- Hot water in
- Electricity
- Waste water out

This is specifically for cold water in.

Does your washing machine need hot water as well? Or does it heat the water if a cycle calls for hot water?

Electricity is probably the easiest piece, at least for a washing machine. Most US/Canada washing machines use a standard 120V 15A receptacle. On the other hand, if you want to install a dryer then you typically need 240V **and** also figure out how to handle venting the hot air out.

What about waste water drainage? That may be more than you realize. A typical washing machine pushes out the water very quickly, possibly faster than your sink drain can take it.

What I suggest looking at is a "portable" washing machine. These typically get water using an adapter on a regular kitchen faucet. **No permanent installation or changes to existing plumbing**, which solves the landlord problem (the only effect on the landlord is higher water usage) and solves the "things can go wrong" problem, at least with respect to plumbing installation.

Comment: Drainage shouldn't be much of an issue, it's right next to a toilet, so just put the end of the drain hose into the bowl and make 105 % sure it can't slip out. Regarding the dryer, aren't vent-less condensing dryers a thing your side of the pond? (Perhaps they could even be 120V only given their vastly lower current draw.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, so added a T piece with two outlets and its own tap as shown.
The source tap at the bottom is old and didn't quite turn off. I feel happier having an extra tap.

For your purpose, may have to add a bush to increase the size at one junction.

In my area it is permitted to do your own plumbing after the non-return valve. (upstream of this plumbing - so not in photo)

[image]